# How to get a string after a symbol

Tags: php, delimiter

I have this string in php do I use delimiter?

Ex:

```
Animal: Dog
Color: white
Sex: male
```

I need to get the word after `animal:`, `color:`, and `sex:`.

String have new line after category

Comment: Hint: you might want to use something like [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = 'Animal: Dog
Color: white
Sex: male';

$lines = explode("\n", $str);

$output = array(); // Initialize

foreach ($lines as $v) {
  $pair = explode(": ", $v);
  $output[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}

print_r($output);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [Animal] => Dog
    [Color] => white
    [Sex] => male
)
```

Comment: This fits what i need.thanks dude and also thanks a lot to all who shared their codes..

Comment: @user2439219 accept answer if you got time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function in php

```
$str = 'Animal: Dog';

$arr = explode(':',$str);
print_r($arr);
```

Here `$arr[0] = 'Animal' and $arr[1] = 'Dog'.`

Comment: `$arr[1]` in this case will be `' Dog'`, actually, thanks to the space in there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`preg_match_all`](http://uk.php.net/preg-match-all):

```
$string = 'Animal: Dog
Color: white
Sex: male';

preg_match_all('#([^:]+)\s*:\s*(.*)#m', $string, $m);
$array = array_combine(array_map('trim', $m[1]), array_map('trim', $m[2])); // Merge the keys and values, and remove(trim) newlines/spaces ...
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Animal] => Dog
    [Color] => white
    [Sex] => male
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = "Animal: Dog Color: White Sex: male";
    $str = str_replace(": ", "=",  $str);
    $str = str_replace(" ", "&",  $str);
    parse_str($str, $array); 

?>
```

Then call the value using $array's keys.

```
<?php
     echo $array["Animal"]; //Dog
?>
```